# Is there a way to skip logging hex form from System.Net?

Tags: c#, debugging, logging

I've enabled System.Net logging in application configuration and problem is, that xml messages in log file look like this:

```
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [7148] 00000000 : 3C 73 3A 45 6E 76 65 6C-6F 70 65 20 78 6D 6C 6E : <s:Envelope xmln 
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [7148] 00000010 : 73 3A 73 3D 22 68 74 74-70 3A 2F 2F 73 63 68 65 : s:s="http://sche
```

which makes it very hard to read (as long as I don't need hex representation, and textual representation is several symbols wide). Is there a way to tell .net to skip hex part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `tracemode` to `protocolonly` as explained in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824.aspx):

```
<source name="System.Net" tracemode="protocolonly" maxdatasize="2048">
    <listeners>
        <add name="MyLog" />
    </listeners>
</source>
```

Comment: I get warning: The 'tracemode' attribute is not allowed, though it's not an error and works fine.